# Is the bandgap energy at the same level quantasized as other orbits of electrons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics

Usually to excite an electron to an 'higher orbit' there has to be an exact quantity of energy of a photon. I don't know hów exact this quantity of photonenergy has to be, but is there a difference between a 'normal' excitation of an electron and the 'jump' from the valence band to the conduction band?

With other words, how far does it matter how much the energy of a photon should be to create current in a solarcell?

And if there is a difference, what is the cause of that?

And is this difference also involved in the difference between a photovoltaic effect and a photoelectric effect?

Comment: In a crystal, the energy levels from all the different atoms get split up and get so close to each other that they can be treated approximately as a continuous band.

Comment: A single atom has very clearly defined energy levels. An agglomeration of billions of atoms results in those energy levels being spread out - they can't all occupy the exact same energy. So, the bandgap energy is well defined (maximum in the valence band to minimum in the conduction band), but photons with higher energy can then lift an electron from somewhere in the valence band to somewhere in the conduction band. The electron/hole will then rapidly thermalize on down, so you are losing some efficiency in the conversion.